# Is there a way to confirm whether one answer is equivalent to another (say integral answers)?

Tags: discussion

Is there  a way to confirm whether one answer is equivalent to another (say integral answers) automatically like say on wolfram alpha or something? I keep answering these trig integrals and always get different answers than in solutions manual but don't wanna have to ask whether each one of these is right or wrong on this site. Is there a way to confirm two answers are equal or not?

Comment: This would be a good main site question.